# Show text using Javascript in the style of HTML5 input validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form with several inputs.  I can verify most of the inputs client side, and I am using HTML5's input validation for this.  For one input though, I can only know if it is valid server side.

In the case that the server says that the input is invalid, how can I display a message for this input that is identical in style to the other HTML5's input validation messages?

Comment: set `input.validationMessage` and or `input.setCustomValidity()` using info from the ajax return. this will let you change the text that appears in the native validation error message, ensuring it visually matches the other messages and making it look uniform and professional.

Comment: Please spell-check your question title.

Answer (score -1):

You could use an Ajax request to send the form data to the server. Then the server validates the data and returns success or invalid. Then with Javascript you can show the validation messages when invalid is returned.

UPDATE: This can be done with the Javascript Validation API. The .setCustomValidity() method can either be passed:
an empty string. This sets the field as valid so .checkValidity() and .validity.valid will return true, or
a string containing an error message which will be shown in the message bubble (if used). The message also flags the field as failing so .checkValidity() and .validity.valid will return false and the invalid event will fire.

Source: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-forms-javascript-constraint-validation-api/

Comment: "Then with Javascript you can show the validation messages when invalid is returned."  Yes, that is why I am asking.  How can I do this?

Comment: "How to use AJAX" is really too broad of a question. There are many tutorials on using AJAX to send an item to a server and get a response. But you need to also have the server code to receive, process and return the response. You need to narrow your target question.

Comment: @mrunion I am not asking about AJAX.  I am asking about how to use Javascript to show in a message in the style HTML's input validation.  I don't care if the page has to be refreshed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question, but I updated my answer with the correct info.